# Подключение к базе Oracle через C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle

Совсем еще новичок. Делаю программу по туториалу. Построил такой код но после Вывода "Connection successful!" не запускается метод на запрос данных. Что нужно дописать чтобы она срабатывала?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CsOracleTutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            OracleConnection conn = DBOracleUtils.GetDBConnection();

            //Console.WriteLine("Get Connection: " + conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString, "Successful Connection");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("## ERROR: " + ex.Message);
                Console.Read();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");

            Console.Read();
        }


        private static void QueryEmployee(OracleConnection conn)
        {
            string sql = "Select Emp_Id, Emp_No, Emp_Name, Mng_Id from Employee";

            // Создать объект Command.
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql);

            // Сочетать Command с Connection.
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;


            using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // Индекс (index) столбца Emp_ID в команде SQL.
                        int empIdIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Emp_Id"); // 0


                        long empId = Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetValue(0));

                        // Индекс столбца Emp_No = 1.
                        string empNo = reader.GetString(1);
                        int empNameIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Emp_Name");// 2
                        string empName = reader.GetString(empNameIndex);


                        int mngIdIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Mng_Id");

                        long? mngId = null;

                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(mngIdIndex))
                        {
                            mngId = Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetValue(mngIdIndex));
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("empIdIndex:" + empIdIndex);
                        Console.WriteLine("EmpId:" + empId);
                        Console.WriteLine("EmpNo:" + empNo);
                        Console.WriteLine("EmpName:" + empName);
                        Console.WriteLine("MngId:" + mngId);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что бы метод запустился, его необходимо вызвать. После открытия соединения `conn.Open();` добавить вызов данного метода, передавая в него это соединение `QueryEmployee(conn);`.

Comment: Ага разобрался. Спасибо!!